# How to add hyperlink for column 0 cells django templates

Tags: html, django-templates

I have for loops like this in my templates:

```
{% for row in my_data %}
     {%  for item in row %}
            <td>{{ item }}</td>
      {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Where do I insert the hyperlink for all items on first column (I have multiple rows with multiple columns in my_data)?

```
<td><a href="../{{ item }}">{{ item }}</a></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did:

```
{% for row in my_data %}
     {%  for item in row %}
         {% if forloop.counter == 1 %}
             <td><a href="../{{ item }}">{{ item }}</a></td>
         {% else %}
             <td>{{ item }}</td>
     {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

It worked.